# How to arrange an invitation letter for research visit in another university (for PhD student)?

Tags: phd, student-exchange, invitations

I'm a first-year PhD student in Communication and Media Science. As part of the study program, I am obliged to visit the university abroad (the best would be in next year).

There I need to carry out part of my research, but I would also like to be able to participate in classes with other doctoral students and observe the work of the lecturers. I would like to do this (3 months) at universities in Finland and the Netherlands.

Is this feasible?  Where should I start? I have never taken part in an academic exchange before. Every advice would be appreciated.

Comment: @MorganRodgers Well, not necessarily. Sending students abroad or receiving students from abroad is common in several places and people from these places may have good general suggestions.

Comment: When I went to Academic Exchange Office, they said that we can start the procedure, when I'll receive an invitation letter. But they did not said how to get this letter. They were like: "it is obvious lol". But for me it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, in the U.S., since people in Paris are vaguely acquainted with me, some years ago I was asked to be a supervisor for an Ecole Poly undergrad's "senior project", more-or-less. I had spare time-and-energy at the time, and the people asking me were known to me, and certainly gave the impression that they were not just spamming. (The student was very good, and later won a prize for his paper, "back home".)

So I think if you can get your local faculty to contact people who know them, and can recommend you to them, it might work well. (But, sure, sometimes people are already over-committed, as I am currently, so I sadly had to decline a similar offer, although I knew it would have been quite fun... Just not enough time.)

Comment: This answer can be generalized, I think. Person to person contacts are the best, if available. It is a bit harder when they are not.

Comment: @Buffy, yes, indeed, as always, personal contacts are the most compelling. And, at the same time, it is mildly disturbing to realize that this palpable fact un-levels the playing field for outsiders. I'm currently tasked with trying to correct some of these problems... and, although I was aware of the problems before, there _is_ a big problem of outsiders vs. insiders. Not easily repaired.

Comment: ... and, currently, I'm going through grad program applications... where I see both privilege and the opposite... and how to judge what a person who'd encountered hostility and disbelief might have done if they had the opposite... etc. Some of my colleagues reasonably kid me that I am "paying back for my own lifetime of privilege". Ha. Yes, actually. Notably, it's not that I didn't work hard, etc., but that other hard-working people do have obstacles that I did not, etc. It's not even the "may you live in interesting times" thing... [cont'd]

Comment: ... [cont'd] but "may you live in times with better social justice".

Comment: ... and then it would be a bit of a curse, but with positive content.

Comment: @paulgarrett but when I would prepare an e-mail to you regarding my application, what would you like to receive? If I would send to you kind of letter explaing why I want to work with you + academic CV + confirmation of enrolment from my university + recommendation letter from my supervisor, would be enough? Or if I first ping you on ResearchGate/Academia.edu, then after chit-chat send you e-mail?

Comment: Because I can't count on my faculty - they are like "why on Earth do you need to go abroad?"

Comment: @Van2020, it'd be more like I might be able to do a favor for a colleague, for someone I know. I'm generally already fully-enough committed that it is not feasible to entertain "walk ons", in general, because the effort needed to appraise them is substantial. If, instead, a friend of mine has already done that screening, it reduces my workload.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll talk with my supervisor first - that will be the best thing to do as first step.